# How do I automatically load a layout into my AvalonDock instance?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, avalondock

I have integrated AvalonDock 2.0 into my application. I've bound the document and anchor-able sources to my view-model which are rendered with the proper user controls via `DataTemplate`s.

I can load and save layouts with the `XmlLayoutSerializer`. I need to support loading predefined layouts on demand (via `Button`s and `ICommand`s). That works as well.

The thing I can't get working is loading a serialized layout automatically when the `DockingManager` is done loading the view-models and their views (user controls).

I've tried loading my layout on `DockingManager.DataContextChanged` but I think it fires too early because the layout loads with the documents in the hidden section and duplicate documents in the visible sections. The rendered panes do not reflect the loaded layout and when the layout is saved again the duplicates are accumulated in the hidden section.

```
<ad:DockingManager Name="DockingManager"
                   DataContext="{Binding Project}"
                   DataContextChanged="DockingManager_OnDataContextChanged"
                   ActiveContent="{Binding Active}"
                   AnchorablesSource="{Binding Anchorables}"
                   DocumentsSource="{Binding Documents}">
    <ad:DockingManager.Theme>
        <ad:AeroTheme/>
    </ad:DockingManager.Theme>

    <ad:DockingManager.LayoutItemTemplateSelector>
        <views:PanesTemplateSelector>
            <views:PanesTemplateSelector.ChartTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <views:Chart/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </views:PanesTemplateSelector.ChartTemplate>
            <views:PanesTemplateSelector.WorkspaceTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Views:Workspace/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </views:PanesTemplateSelector.WorkspaceTemplate>
            ...
        </views:PanesTemplateSelector>
    </ad:DockingManager.LayoutItemTemplateSelector>

    <ad:DockingManager.LayoutItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ad:LayoutItem}">
            <Setter Property="Title" Value="{Binding Model.DisplayText}"/>
            <Setter Property="ContentId" Value="{Binding Model.ContentId}"/>
        </Style>
    </ad:DockingManager.LayoutItemContainerStyle>

    <ad:LayoutRoot>
        <!--<ad:LayoutPanel>
            <ad:LayoutDocumentPane/>
            <ad:LayoutAnchorablePane/>
        </ad:LayoutPanel>-->
    </ad:LayoutRoot>
</ad:DockingManager>
```

... and the code-behind ...

```
private void SaveLayout() {
    if (this.DataContext == null)
        return;
    var xmlLayoutSerializer = new XmlLayoutSerializer(this.DockingManager);
    var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    using (var textWriter = new StringWriter(stringBuilder))
        xmlLayoutSerializer.Serialize(textWriter);
    var serialized = stringBuilder.ToString();
    (this.DataContext as dynamic).XmlSerializedAndEscapedLayout = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(serialized);
}
private void LoadLayout()
{
    if (DataContext == null)
        return;
    var encoded = (DataContext as dynamic).XmlSerializedAndEscapedLayout;
    var window = Window.GetWindow(this);
    window.Closing += (sender, args) => SaveLayout();
    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(encoded))
        return;
    var serialized = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(encoded);
    var xmlLayoutSerializer = new XmlLayoutSerializer(DockingManager);
    using (var stringReader = new StringReader(serialized))
        xmlLayoutSerializer.Deserialize(stringReader);
}
private void DockingManager_OnDataContextChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.NewValue != null) // A type check here would be best, I know.
        LoadLayout();
}
```

... And the view-model ...

```
public class ProjectViewModel
{
    public IModel Model { get; private set; }
    public String SerializedLayout { get; set; }
    public ViewModelBase Active { get; set; }
    private readonly ObservableCollection<ViewModelBase> documents;
    public ReadOnlyObservableCollection<ViewModelBase> Documents { get; private set; }
    private readonly ObservableCollection<ViewModelBase> anchorables;
    public ReadOnlyObservableCollection<ViewModelBase> Anchorables { get; private set; }

    public ProjectViewModel(String filePath, String serializedLayout)
    {
        SerializedLayout = serializedLayout;
        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
        {
            IModelRepository modelRepository = Ioc.DependencyInjectionContainer.DefaultContainer.Resolve<IModelRepository>();
            Model = modelRepository.Load(fileStream);
        }
        documents = new ObservableCollection<ViewModelBase>();
        anchorables = new ObservableCollection<ViewModelBase>();
        documents.Add(new Workspace());
        anchorables.Add(new RiskLimitsViewModel(Model.RiskLimits));
        ...
        Documents = new ReadOnlyObservableCollection<ViewModelBase>(documents);
        Anchorables = new ReadOnlyObservableCollection<ViewModelBase>(anchorables);
    }
}
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Nick, out of interest (I m trying to write an MVVM app using A Dock myself): is your solution truly MVVM with real separation of concerns? The fact that your VM has a property "serializedlayout" seems like there is something A Dock specific in your VM, ie the VM knows more than it should about the view...

Comment: Would it not be better for the VM to define some kind of load and unload event to which the V could subscribe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had to add this in the XAML...

```
...
</ad:DockingManager.Theme>
<ad:DockingManager.LayoutUpdateStrategy>
    <views:LayoutUpdateStrategy/>
</ad:DockingManager.LayoutUpdateStrategy>

<ad:DockingManager.LayoutItemTemplateSelector>
...
```

...and  this in the code-behind...

```
class LayoutUpdateStrategy : ILayoutUpdateStrategy
{
    private bool BeforeInsertContent(LayoutRoot layout, LayoutContent anchorableToShow)
    {
        var viewModel = (ViewModelBase) anchorableToShow.Content;
        var layoutContent = layout.Descendents().OfType<LayoutContent>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.ContentId == viewModel.ContentId);
        if (layoutContent == null)
            return false;
        layoutContent.Content = anchorableToShow.Content;
        // Add layoutContent to it's previous container
        var layoutContainer = layoutContent.GetType().GetProperty("PreviousContainer", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(layoutContent, null) as ILayoutContainer;
        if (layoutContainer is LayoutAnchorablePane)
            (layoutContainer as LayoutAnchorablePane).Children.Add(layoutContent as LayoutAnchorable);
        else if (layoutContainer is LayoutDocumentPane)
            (layoutContainer as LayoutDocumentPane).Children.Add(layoutContent);
        else
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        return true;
    }
    public bool BeforeInsertAnchorable(LayoutRoot layout, LayoutAnchorable anchorableToShow, ILayoutContainer destinationContainer)
    {
        return BeforeInsertContent(layout, anchorableToShow);
    }
    public void AfterInsertAnchorable(LayoutRoot layout, LayoutAnchorable anchorableShown) {}
    public bool BeforeInsertDocument(LayoutRoot layout, LayoutDocument anchorableToShow, ILayoutContainer destinationContainer)
    {
        return BeforeInsertContent(layout, anchorableToShow);
    }
    public void AfterInsertDocument(LayoutRoot layout, LayoutDocument anchorableShown) {}
}
```

Comment: Could someone provide any explanation please?

Answer (score 0):

I used this :

XAML:

```
<avalonDock:DockingManager 
x:Name="dockManager" 
AllowMixedOrientation="True" 
DocumentClosing="dockManager_DocumentClosing" 
AnchorablesSource="{Binding ListUserPanelAnchorable}"
DocumentsSource="{Binding ListUserPanel}"
Theme="{Binding avalondockTheme}">
```

Model :

```
public ObservableCollection<UserPanel> _ListUserPanelAnchorable;
ReadOnlyObservableCollection<UserPanel> _readonyFiles = null;
public ReadOnlyObservableCollection<UserPanel> ListUserPanelAnchorable
{
    get
    {
        if (_readonyFiles == null)
            _readonyFiles = new ReadOnlyObservableCollection<UserPanel>(_ListUserPanelAnchorable);

        return _readonyFiles;
    }
}
```

xaml.cs:

```
private void loadLayout()
{
    //dockPanelModel.ListUserPanel.Clear();
    //dockPanelModel.ListUserPanelAnchorable.Clear();
    var serializer = new XmlLayoutSerializer(dockManager);
    serializer = new XmlLayoutSerializer(dockManager);
    serializer.LayoutSerializationCallback += (s, args) =>
    {
        args.Content = userPanel;
                dockPanelModel._ListUserPanelAnchorable.Add(userPanel);
    }
}

public AvaladonDockPanel()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.Loaded += AvaladonDockPanel_Loaded;                
}       

void AvaladonDockPanel_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    loadLayout();          
}
```

userpanel:

```
public class UserPanel
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string ToolTip { get; set; }
    public string IconSource { get; set; }

    private Guid _contentGuid = Guid.NewGuid();
    public Guid ContentId
    {
        get { return _contentGuid; }
        set { _contentGuid = value; }
    }


    private UserControl _UserInterface;
    public UserControl UserInterface { get { return _UserInterface; } set { _UserInterface = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("UserInterface"); } }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("PropertyChanged-> {0}", propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

binding avalon to userpanel:

```
<avalonDock:DockingManager.LayoutItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type avalonDock:LayoutItem}">
        <Setter Property="Title" Value="{Binding Model.Title}"/>
        <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding Model.ToolTip}"/>
        <Setter Property="IconSource" Value="{Binding Model.IconSource}" />
        <Setter Property="ContentId" Value="{Binding Model.ContentId}"/>
    </Style>
</avalonDock:DockingManager.LayoutItemContainerStyle>
<avalonDock:DockingManager.LayoutItemTemplate >
    <DataTemplate >
        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding UserInterface}"  />
    </DataTemplate>
</avalonDock:DockingManager.LayoutItemTemplate>
```

Comment: What is `userPanel` and where is it defined?