# How to save position of undocked dynamic tabs in avalondock?

Tags: wpf, avalondock

Is it possible to save positions and size of undocked tabs in AvalonDock?

Other things like docked and resized panels, which are visible and witch not, are properly saved and reloaded on application start. Only thing I can't force to be saved are tabs that I drag creating floating windows. Those windows after I reload application are docked as tabs again.

Answer (score 1):

This [Link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/719143/AvalonDock-Tutorial-Part-Load-Save-Layout) gives a good example how you can save the layout of AvalonDock. It work with the sample given in the post.

Here we have one more [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14585556/how-do-i-automatically-load-a-layout-into-my-avalondock-instance) about `How do I automatically load a layout into my AvalonDock instance?`